# Faster alternatives to sorting std::vector

Tags: c++, caching, hashmap, alignment, cpu

I have a hash_map with an unsinged int (user id) as the key and a vector of dates as the value.
I.e.

```
// key - user id, value - vector of dates from 2020
hash_map<unsigned, vector<unsigned short>>;

[1] = { 14 }            // 2020/1/14
[2] = { 18, 25, 32 }    // 2020/01/18, 2020/01/25, 2020/02/01
```

These values in a vector represent when a user will be notified, but there's one rule: you cannot notify the same user more than twice (can be changed in a config) in a week. To check if I can add a new notify date to a user I search for the first date that has less than 7 days difference with the inserting one, then check if the next date in the vector has more than 7 days difference and insert a new element if true. After inserting I sort the vector. Every 24 hours I clear all elements up to today().

**The question is:**
I need to do something with the value type, as it's what makes everything work slow (in average, there're 300.000.000 changes per day, i.e. the same amount of linear searching and around 25M sorting). Do you have any ideas what structure, datatype or an algorithm to use to get rid of sort()?

Using **unordered_set** is a bad idea.

1. linear search in a vector is faster if works with less than ~100 elements compared to unordered_set, and I don't have more than 5 dates per a person usually.
2. I can't allow to waste 3 times more RAM to store such a structure.
3. I can't align unordered_set to the 64Bytes of L1 processor cache.

p.s. My hash map takes 470mb memory for the map and keys plus 304mb for the values.

Comment: You should only have to sort the vector once.  After that, you can use `upper_bound`/`lower_bound` to find where the new element should go into the vector and handle the rejection or insertion from there.  Since your vector looks like days in a year, at most it would be size 366 and inserting into that isn't terrible as vector has very good cache performance.

Comment: You miss something. Inserting in a middle of the vector forces it to do a lot of reallocates. No, my vector is max the size of 5. If it'd be 365, I'd need to use over 20885MB of RAM. (I have 30M keys, so it'd give us 30M of vector the size of 365)

Comment: Can't you just call `reserve(5)` or something if you know your vectors are supposed to have a max size of 5 and want to avoid reallocations during the runtime?

Comment: There wont be a lot of reallocations.  At most you'd have one.  There will be "a lot" of moving elements backwards, but processors are pretty good at doing that these days.  Inserting into the middle of vector is often faster then any other data structures for smaller sized objects/smaller size vectors: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Comment: Yes, this is a good point. The vector basically is the best structure in C++ for almost anything, this is exactly why I chose it. But are there anything else? Perhaps a complete different approach. For examples, a structure that'd somehow allow you to store required dates, without need to do sort them and without decreasing performance/drastically increased memory usage. Or that would let you know if the date can be reserved for O(1). I tried to come up with something new but always ended up with the same vector-sort thing.

Comment: If you use a byte worth of bitmap for each week that's less memory use than your current worstcase.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gliding window over the last 7 days to keep track of notifications.
One can use "unsigned char" as a bit vector, bit 0 being today, bit 1 yesterday and so on.

```
unsigned char last7Days= 0;
// if 0 or 1 notification in the last week, add one today
if (count_bits(last7Days) < 2) last7Days |=1;

// update notifications each day
last7Days = (last7Days << 1) & 0x7F; // shift and mask 7 days
```

Comment: 1) If I have a notification on the 1st day and 488th day - I'll have to either waste another byte tracking the weeks' number or to have a lot of empty weeks in my vector between dates.
2) I'll have to shift all elements in the vector, not just the first char. It's cheaper to shift vector's first element, not to apply the mask on each.
If I got you right, this method isn't the best

Comment: I thought the newly inserted notification represents today(), not some future date. İf that's not the case, my suggestion won't work.